# Unexpected value 'AnyComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular2 and I got this problem when tryng to use two classes in the same Typescript file.

At compile time doesn't give me any error but when I try to execute the page the console.log is giving this error:

```
Error: BaseException@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:5116:27
    CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata/<@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13274:35
    CompileMetadataResolver</CompileMetadataResolver.prototype.getNgModuleMetadata@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13261:21
    RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:28
    RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:36
    RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:20
    PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:20
    PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype.bootstrapModule@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:20
    @http://www.my.app/panel-module/app/main.js:4:1
    @http://www.my.app/panel-module/app/main.js:1:31
    @http://www.my.app/panel-module/app/main.js:1:2
    Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:20
    Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:25
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:586:53
    Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:24
    Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:29
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:491:26
    F/</g@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:10016
    F/<@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:10138
    a.exports/k@http://www.my.app/panel-module/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:14293

    Evaluating http://www.my.app/panel-module/app/main.js
    Error loading http://www.my.app/panel-module/app/main.js
```

Below is my component typescript file.

// MyComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
})

export class MyObject {
  id: number;
}


export class MyComponent {
   obj: MyObject;

   // unecessary code
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to change the order of your classes, then there is no problem to have multiple classes in the same file.
Cause in your case that `decorator @Component` is now being used for your class `MyObject` instead of `MyComponent` !

The `decorator @Component` needs to be directly in front of your Component definition!!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export class MyObject1 {
  id: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
})
export class MyComponent {
   obj: MyObject;

   // unecessary code
}

export class MyObject2 {
  id: number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed on the other way but I didn't know why I needed to do that.

Comment: because that `decorator @Component` needs to be in front of your component. without this decorator, your component isn't a real component.. otherwise it's just a class..

Comment: thanks, so the component should defined first before used in the module.

Comment: I had the reverse problem; I wanted to define a `Directive` but was using the `Component` decorator. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed it:

**Put the MyObject into a separated file and import him.**

// MyObject.ts

```
export class MyObject {
  id: number;
}
```

// MyComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyObject } from 'path/to/MyObject';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
})

export class MyComponent {
   obj: MyObject;

   // unecessary code
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to do that instead of just place your `myObject` before your component, as @mxii suggested?

Comment: I did that before @mxii post the answer. I didn't know what the right answer but this worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, my case i just had some js logic where it could'nd be

```
<my-tag [HTML]="sourcesHtml ? sourcesHtml[i] : ''">
```

changed to

```
<my-tag [HTML]="sourcesHtml[i]">
```

and error was removed