# Group array in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a json response like this

**JSON response**

```
"Terms": [
            {
                "Help": "Terms",
                "EventType": "Success",
                "Srno": 1,
                "Heading": "Discount Condition",
                "TermsDesc": "50 % Discount on 1st Cab Ride"
            },
            {
                "Help": "Terms",
                "EventType": "Success",
                "Srno": 2,
                "Heading": "Discount Condition",
                "TermsDesc": "20% Discount on Nights more than 8"
            },
            {
                "Help": "Terms",
                "EventType": "Success",
                "Srno": 1,
                "Heading": "Stay Condition",
                "TermsDesc": "No More than 10% Discount on Less than 4 Nights Stay"
            },
            {
                "Help": "Terms",
                "EventType": "Success",
                "Srno": 2,
                "Heading": "Stay Condition",
                "TermsDesc": "20% Discount on Nights more than 8"
            },
            {
                "Help": "Terms",
                "EventType": "Success",
                "Srno": 3,
                "Heading": "Discount Condition",
                "TermsDesc": "No More than 10% Discount on Less than 4 Nights Stay"
            }
        ],
```

I want to group it by `Heading`. Similar `Heading` should have it's `TermsDesc` for eg. **Discount Condition** and **Stay Condition** from Response

**Discount Condition**

- "50 % Discount on 1st Cab Ride"
- "20% Discount on Nights more than 8"
- "condition 3"

**Stay Condition**

- "50 % Discount on 1st Cab Ride"
- "20% Discount on Nights more than 8"
- "condition 3"

Component function where I'm getting response

```
 getTerms(){
    this.quoteService.getTerms()
    .subscribe(
      terms => {
        this.terms = terms.resultData.Terms;
        this.notes = terms.resultData.ImpNotes;
        this.exclusions = terms.resultData.Exclusions;
        var arr=[];
        var strHeading;
        var title;
        var temp = 0;
        var listing = [];
        for(let i=0;i<this.terms.length;i++) {
          strHeading=this.terms[i].Heading;
          title=this.terms[i].TermsAndConditionsDesc;
          if(!this.uniqTerm[temp]){
            this.uniqTerm[temp] = [];
          }
          if (arr.indexOf(strHeading) !== -1) {
            this.uniqTerm[temp].push({"header":strHeading});
          } 
          else {
               arr.push(strHeading);               
               this.uniqTerm[temp].push({"header":strHeading});               
               listing.push({"title":title});
               this.uniqTerm[temp].push({"title":title});
               temp++;                 
          }
      },
      response => {
        if (response.status == 404) {
        }
      });
  }
```

How can I create Array so I can use it in `*ngFor`?

I think I would need something like

```
[0]:object
     Heading:"Discount Condition"
     TermsDesc: object
                term: Term1 
                term: Term2

[1]:object
     Heading:"Stay Condition"
     TermsDesc: object
                term: Term1 
                term: Term2
```

but don't know how to achieve this in angular2
please help me here or if anyone have better suggestion, I would be glad to try

Thanks

Comment: use `groupBy` operator

Comment: @Skeptor In `ngFor`?

Comment: give me a minute, I am doing rxjs solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution after some digging, still Slava Utesinov's answer also works but it needs to install `linq-es2015`.

```
const groupedObj = this.terms.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
    if(!prev[cur["Heading"]]) {
        prev[cur["Heading"]] = [cur];
    } else {
        prev[cur["Heading"]].push(cur);
    }
    return prev;
}, {});
this.TermCons = Object.keys(groupedObj)
.map(Heading => ({ Heading, TermsDesc: groupedObj[Heading] }));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [linq-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq-es2015) library this way:

```
import { asEnumerable } from 'linq-es2015';

class Term
{
    public Help: string;
    public EventType: string;
    public Srno: number;
    public Heading: string;
    public TermsDesc: string;
}

//somewhere in component
this.terms: Term[];
this.result = asEnumerable(this.terms).GroupBy(x => x.Heading, x => x, (key, b) => { return { Heading: key, TermsDesc: asEnumerable(b).ToArray() } }).ToArray();

//template
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let term of result">
       {{term.Heading}}
       <ul>
           <li *ngFor="let item of term.TermsDesc">{{item.TermsDesc}}</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I'm getting response(this.terms) in `.subscribe`. And I'm unable to use this in `.subscribe()`

Comment: Why unable? `this.terms = terms.resultData.Terms; this.result = asEnumerable(this.terms)...`

Comment: getting `Unexpected value 'TermsComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule' angular2`  error

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001294/unexpected-value-anycomponent-declared-by-the-module-appmodule), be attentive with `@Component` decorator. I think it is due to new `Term` class and wrong order of classes.

Comment: Thanks, let me try again